# Extract number from a string

Tags: c#, regex

I need to get all numbers from a string like this:

```
"156234   something 567345 another thing 45789 anything"
```

The result should be a collection of numbers having:

```
156234, 567345, 45789
```

I tried `@"\d+"`, but it will only give me `156234`.

EDIT: The numbers are integers, however they can also occur like this  "156234   something 567345 another thing 45789 anything2345". In this case I only need the integers i.e  156234, 567345, 45789 and not  156234, 567345, 45789,2345.

Also the integers which i dont want will always be preceed with a text for ex:anything2345.

Comment: What type of numbers?  Only integers, or can there be floating point number?  Numbers larger than `int`?

Comment: Your regex matches the string example you have. Are you sure you're iterating over all the matches?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Everything is ok with your regex, you just need to come through all the matches.

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\d+");

foreach (Match match in regex.Matches("156234 something 567345 another thing 45789 anything"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You want to split on the characters, not the digits. Use the capital D

```
string[] myStrings = Regex.Split(sentence, @"\D+");
```

[Source](http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-split)

Comment: Like the creativity of this solution +1

Answer (score 2):

If 2345 should not be matched in your revised sample string (156234 something 567345 another thing 45789 anything2345), you could use Dima's solution but with the regex:

```
\b\d+\b
```

This assures that the number is surrounded by word boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

This'z in java. You don't actually need a Regex.. just a normal replaceAll should do the trick for you! : For ex : You can strip off the Non-Digits, and then split and calculate the sum.

```
  public static int getSumOfNumbers(String s) {
    int sum = 0;
    String x = s.replaceAll("\\D+", " ");
    String[] a = x.split(" ");
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
         sum += Integer.parseInt(a[i]);
    System.out.println(x + " : and sum is : "+sum);
    return sum;
}
```